# dragUI not draggable when created with insertUI shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I use the `insertUI()` function to create new `dragUI()` dynamically. Unfortunatly, the newly created `dragUI` does not behave as expected. I can’t drag them as `dragUI` that were created from the `ui` initial function.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyDND)

ui <- fluidPage(
actionButton('insertBtn', 'Insert'), 
dropUI("Box", row_n = 3, col_n = 3, style = "height: 200px; width: 700px"),
dragUI("Drag0",style = "display: inline-block; height: 100px; width: 100px",tags$a("Initial"))
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) {
observeEvent(input$insertBtn, {
insertUI(
selector = '#Box',
where = c("afterEnd"), 
ui = (dragUI(id="newDragUI",style = "display: inline-block; height: 100px; width: 100px",tags$a("new")))
)
})
})
```

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific about what the problem is and what type of behavior you are expecting.

Comment: There was a bug in shinyDND when used with insertUI or renderUI. I found a related topic on GitHub [link](https://github.com/ayayron/shinydnd/issues/2). It seems that the version of shinyDND actually available on CRAN still contains the bug. When downloading the package from GitHUb, it works. Thanks.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283202/how-to-refer-to-reactive-element-in-ui-r-in-shiny