# order for jqui_sortable not returned when using insertUI in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjqui

I found this related question: [dragUI not draggable when created with insertUI shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983947/dragui-not-draggable-when-created-with-insertui-shiny)

I want to insert an arbitrary number of ui elements inside a `jqui_sortable()`, and have the order of the elements available inside the server function.

If I know beforehand how many elements are needed I can call the `jqui_sortable()` function inside `insertUI` and then access the order of the elements in the server:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "Add"),
  div(id = "foo")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(selector = "#foo",
             where = "beforeEnd",
             ui = jqui_sortable(tags$ul(
               id = paste0('lst', input$add),
               tags$li('A'),
               tags$li('B'),
               tags$li('C')
             )))
  })

  observe({
    cat(str(input$lst_order1))
    cat(str(input$lst_order2))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you run the above app, you will see the order of the first two lists that are inserted printed to the console. Changing the order of the elements also prints to the console.

However, if I try to put the `jqui_sortable()` in the UI and insert only the elements, the order is not printed. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "add"),
  jqui_sortable(tags$ul(id = "lst")),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#lst",
      where = "beforeEnd",
      ui = tags$li(paste0("test", input$add))
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    cat(str(input$lst_order))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How can I create sortable elements and retrieve the order of the elements on the page at any given time? Solution does not have to employ {shinyjqui}.

I crossposted this on {shinyjqui} GitHub page, but I'm not sure this is a bug.

### Update:

The {sortable} package gets me slightly closer. However, the order of the elements is not updated when new elements are inserted, only when the order is updated by moving the elements around.

```r
library(shiny)
library(sortable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "add"),
  tags$ul(id = "lst"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text"),
  sortable_js(css_id = "lst",  options = sortable_options(
    onSort = sortable_js_capture_input(input_id = "selected"),
    onLoad = sortable_js_capture_input(input_id = "selected")
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#lst",
      where = "beforeEnd",
      ui = tags$li(paste0("test", input$add))
    )
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({
    req(input$selected)
    input$selected
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work like this. The idea is to destroy the sortable stuff and to re-enable it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "add"),
  tags$ul(id = "lst"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#lst",
      where = "beforeEnd",
      ui = tags$li(paste0("test", input$add))
    )
    jqui_sortable("#lst", operation = "enable")
  }, priority = 1)
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    jqui_sortable("#lst", operation = "destroy")
  }, priority = 2)
  
  observe({
    cat(str(input$lst_order))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you! Not sure two `observeEvent()` calls is necessary; I think I can just put the `jqui_sortable("#lst", operation = "destroy")`  before the `insertUI()`.